# Excel Formula - Next Wednesday UNLESS Input is Tuesday

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-dates

I have searched many previous queries on this site for an answer and haven't found what I'm looking for. I know the formula that will display the following Wednesday after a given date. However, if the given date is a Tuesday, I want it to display the Wednesday of the following week, not the Wednesday immediately following that Tuesday. Basically if the input is a Tuesday, I want it to skip a Wednesday. Like so:

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| Tuesday 1/16/24 | Wednesday 1/24/24 |
| Wednesday 1/17/24 | Wednesday 1/24/24 |
| Thursday 1/18/24 | Wednesday 1/24/24 |

Is there a way to get excel to do this?

Here is the formula I am currently using and understand (where H5 is the input date):

```
=IF(H5="",--"",(H5+8-WEEKDAY(H5,13)))
```

I'd love to stick with a version of this if possible and modify it so that it returns two Wednesdays out from a Tuesday.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try the following the formula:

[image]

---

```
=IF(H5="","--",H5+8-MOD(H5-3,7))
```

---

Or, Using `#Spill`

```
=LET(α, H5:H7, IF(α="","--",α+8-MOD(α-3,7)))
```

---

Using `WEEKDAY()` it would be like as below:

```
=IF(H5="","--",H5+8-(WEEKDAY(H5,12)-1))
```

---

Or,

```
=LET(α, H5:H7, IF(α="","--",α+8-(WEEKDAY(α,12)-1)))
```

---